# Actionscript Libraries for Augmented Reality

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, augmented-reality

So I have just stumbled upon some augmented reality stuff done in Flash and it got me super excited. I am just looking for some pointers right now. What I would like to be able to do is **overlay images on a webcam at specific GPS coordinates**. The couple of libraries that I've seen (FLARManager and IN2AR) appear to be based on motion tracking which isn't exactly what I'm looking for. Are there any AS3 libraries that can help do this? Many Thanks.

Comment: AS3 libraries? Not that I know of. But you can pull that off with Metaio. You need to do java, C# or Obj-C for that though. Or use their editor. So I suggest that you look into that, even if it isn't AS3 related.

Comment: It looks kind of like what I need but away out of my budget. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the key to your project is to get the user's GPS coordinate, and based on this to 'do stuff'.

If you use the native geo-location classes, you can already approximate the users' GPS position: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/sensors/Geolocation.html 
However, on a desktop it will not work.

For desktop, you can use a Javascript approach in the HTML to feed the data back into the Flash app: [Geolocation in Flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945871/geolocation-in-flash)

Then just do your image overlay code on your webcam image as required (though if you don't require motion tracking, I'd be interested to know what sort of 'augmented reality' your project is doing!)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, what I mean is that I have lots of 'objects' stored in a database with Latitudes and Longitudes and I want to translate those into a 3D space overlaid on an iPhone camera. I think I may have to make a simple library myself with something like Matrix3D.